# How to set Git options with relative path in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, powershell

I have the following project structure and trying to change the default git hooks path from `.git/hooks` to `.githooks`. I found out that the command `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` is responsible for this. But I've been struggling with the relative path in Windows 10, I need to go up 2 times and then specify `.githooks` directory, but any `..\.`, `../.`, `"..\."` doesn't work.
Maybe the problem not only in Windows but also the way how Git handles the config file, where this path will be written

How to specify such a path, for instance, in PowerShell?

Project directories:

```
|
└───.githooks <---I want it here
└───.git
│   └───hooks <---by default it's here
```

**Solved:** `phd` **suggested to use** `git config core.hooksPath ./.githooks` **which works for windows**

Comment: In what way `git config core.hooksPath .githooks` doesn't work? Also try `git config core.hooksPath ./.githooks`

Comment: `git config core.hooksPath ./.githooks` works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Just so you know, storing hooks in the repository is insecure because it allows arbitrary code execution by anyone who can write to the repository.

Answer (score 2):

[`core.hooksPath`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corehooksPath) … can be … relative. A relative path is taken as **relative to the directory where the hooks are run** (see the ["DESCRIPTION" section of githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_description)).

«Before Git invokes a hook, it changes its working directory to either $GIT_DIR in a bare repository or the **root of the working tree in a non-bare repository**.»

(Emphasize mine — *phd*).

To put your `.githooks/` into the root you should provide a relative path to the root which is `./`. So use

```
git config core.hooksPath ./.githooks
```